# Problem with Microprofile Metrics on Wildfly 26

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, metrics, wildfly-26

i'm currently upgrading from Wildfly 20 to Wildfly 26. The `standalone.xml` doesn't start, because of an Injection of `MetricRegistry` and the newly missing `microprofile.metrics-smallrye`-extension (already described under: [MicroProfile Metrics do not show custom metrics on Wildfly 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69479379/microprofile-metrics-do-not-show-custom-metrics-on-wildfly-25)).
But if i start the `standalone-microprofile.xml` or add the extensions (see CLI-commands below), i ran into the same error.

Maybe the Keycloak-Integration-Workaround is conflicting. The Wildfly-internal OIDC adapter is actualy not working in bearer-only-mode. So i installed the current keycloak-client (`keycloak-oidc-wildfly-adapter-16.1.1`) an the workaround (see as last code-template).

```
2022-02-21 12:44:09,176 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."xyz.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."xyz.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: SRMET00013: Description is different from the description in previous usage
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:38)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:510)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)
        at org.jboss.as.weld@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:98)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SRMET00013: Description is different from the description in previous usage
        at io.smallrye.metrics//io.smallrye.metrics.MetricsRegistryImpl.verifyMetadataEquality(MetricsRegistryImpl.java:188)
        at io.smallrye.metrics//io.smallrye.metrics.MetricsRegistryImpl.get(MetricsRegistryImpl.java:459)
        at io.smallrye.metrics//io.smallrye.metrics.MetricsRegistryImpl.get(MetricsRegistryImpl.java:402)
        at io.smallrye.metrics//io.smallrye.metrics.MetricsRegistryImpl.timer(MetricsRegistryImpl.java:371)
        at io.smallrye.metrics//io.smallrye.metrics.setup.MetricsMetadata.registerMetrics(MetricsMetadata.java:111)
        at io.smallrye.metrics//io.smallrye.metrics.setup.MetricCdiInjectionExtension.registerMetrics(MetricCdiInjectionExtension.java:186)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:187)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
        at javax.enterprise.api//javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:124)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
```

CLI-Commands to extend the standalone.xml

```
wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c "/extension=org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics-smallrye:add()"
wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c "/subsystem=microprofile-metrics-smallrye:add()"

wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c "/extension=org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.fault-tolerance-smallrye:add()"
wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c "/subsystem=microprofile-fault-tolerance-smallrye:add()"
```

OIDC-Workaround (installation of keycloak client)

```
embed-server --server-config=${server.config:standalone.xml}

batch
/subsystem=undertow/application-security-domain=other:undefine-attribute(name=security-domain)
/subsystem=undertow/application-security-domain=other:write-attribute(name=http-authentication-factory,value=keycloak-http-authentication)
run-batch

/subsystem=ejb3/application-security-domain=other:write-attribute(name=security-domain,value=KeycloakDomain)

reload
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh i spend a couple of hours to get rid of this problem.. but only minutes after writing this post, i found the "bad guy".
The Microprofile Version 3.3 (on Wildfly 20) ignored annotations (like `@Timed`) at interface-methods. The new Version 4.1 (Wildfly 26) regards them..

pretty easy, afterwards :)

---

**marginal note:**
If you have more than one WAR deployed on your Wildfly and one of them is using the public API of an other one, then you'll run into *problems with hot-deployments*.
I assume, in my case it occurs because i have placed the `Timed`-annotation at the implementation-class and not at the interface, that is used as ResteasyClient-proxy. Every time i deploy the depending WAR **after** the rest-api-defining WAR, i got an exception: `no metric mapped`.
A redeployment of the rest-api-defining WAR fixes this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The /metrics endpoint is queried using an anonymous user usually(prometheus scraper), this means you may have to enable the MONITOR role to include all. That way the anonymous access to /metrics will be able to read the additional thread data.

^^The security impact of this config I'm not sure of.

Answer (score 0):

in my case was that I had duplicated the name with other method in @Timed(name="")...